# Add a second data record in controller (create)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use a "create" view and a corresponding controller to create records.
This is the part of my controller.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Bankbeleg,Belegnummer,Datum,Bezeichnung,Zahlungsart,Brutto,...")] Buchungen buchungen)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(buchungen);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ...
```

That works so far without any problems.

But now I would like to automatically add a second data record as soon as an operation occurs.

I tried this way, but unfortunately, no 2nd data set is created.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Bankbeleg,Belegnummer,Datum,Bezeichnung,Zahlungsart,Brutto,...")] Buchungen buchungen)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(buchungen);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        if (buchungen.Zahlungsart == "PayPal")
        {
            var item = _context.Buchungen
                .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                .LastOrDefault();
            buchungen.Bankbeleg = item.Bankbeleg;
            buchungen.Belegnummer = item.Belegnummer + 1;
            buchungen.Datum = item.Datum;
            buchungen.Bezeichnung = "New Text";
            buchungen.Brutto = item.Brutto / 10;

            _context.Add(buchungen);
        }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Does someone have an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: In the `if(... == "PayPal")` block, you don't call `_context.SaveChangesAsync();` - is this your problem?

Comment: @TimothyG.
This gives me a CS4014 warning.
When I use `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` I got the error message:
**SqlException: Ein expliziter Wert für die Identitätsspalte kann nicht in der Buchungen-Tabelle eingefügt werden, wenn IDENTITY_INSERT auf OFF festgelegt ist.**

It looks like there is a problem with the Id which is defined as "IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL," in the table.
But have not found a solution to this problem.

I tried also to add `buchungen.Id = item.Id + 1;`
But there is the same error.

Comment: That error means the SQL Insert is trying to insert a value for the identity column for that table when the database is suppose to auto generate it.  Can you add the code of your `Buchungen` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution;
It is necessary to set id=0, so that, when the new row gets inserted, the database will create the Identity value for it

```
    if (buchungen.Zahlungsart == "PayPal")
    {
    var item = _context.Buchungen
        .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
        .LastOrDefault();
    buchungen.Id = 0; //<<-- This is important !!!
    ...
```